# Losslessly recording audio and video at the same time

Tags: ffmpeg

how would I be able to record my screen and its audio?
Most I've seen is taking a video, an audio and merging it.
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478548/screen-capture-with-audio-in-ffmpeg

Comment: There are many options (see https://www.google.com/search?q=ffmpeg+capture+display+audio+video+site%253Asuperuser.com and https://www.google.com/search?q=ffmpeg+capture+display+audio+video) but for us to be able to help you would need to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. Show us your command line options and describe what does and does not happen.